# Why an addition of a key does not trigger a watched variable?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have an Object `allevents` asynchronously updated with keys and values. Whenever `allevents` is modified I would like to trigger a recalculation function.

To do so, I use the following Vue structure (in a component, all irrelevant elements removed):

```
export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                //
                allevents: {},
                events: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            //
            mqttMessage(topic, message) {
                const cal = topic.split('/').pop()
                this.allevents[cal] = JSON.parse(message).filter(x => true)
                // following the update above, I was expecting that since 
                // allevents is watched below, the function would trigger
                // as a workaround, I added this line below which fixes the issue
                // but I still would like to understand the lack of trigger
                this.computeEvents()
            },
            // the function ssupposed to be triggred after a chnage, below
            computeEvents() {
                this.events = []
                Object.values(this.allevents).forEach(cal => cal.forEach(e => this.events.push(e)))
            }
        },
        watch: {
            // whenever allevents change, run computeEvents() <-- this does not happen
            allevents() { 
                console.log("events compute triggered")
                this.computeEvents() 
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            //
        }
}
```

**Even though `allevents` is modified and is watched, `computeEvents()` is not started. Why?**

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are victim of a [Reactivity/Change Detection Caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Instead of:

```js
this.allevents[cal] = JSON.parse(message).filter(x => true)
```

Try:

```js
Vue.set(this.allevents, cal, JSON.parse(message).filter(x => true))
```

Or:

```js
this.$set(this.allevents, cal, JSON.parse(message).filter(x => true))
```

Relevant excerpt from [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

> ### Change Detection Caveats
>
> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of
> `Object.observe`), Vue **cannot detect property addition or
> deletion**. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process
> during instance initialization, a property must be present in the
> `data` object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive. For
> example:
>
> ```js
> var vm = new Vue({
>   data: {
>     a: 1
>   }
> })
> // `vm.a` is now reactive
> vm.b = 2
> // `vm.b` is NOT reactive
> ```
>
> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive
> properties to an already created instance. However, it's possible to
> add reactive properties to a nested object using the `Vue.set(object, key, value)` method:
>
> ```js
> Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2)
> ```
>
> You can also use the `vm.$set` instance method, which is an alias to
> the global `Vue.set`:
>
> ```js
> this.$set(this.someObject, 'b', 2)
> ```

Comment: What is `someObject`?

Comment: @adelriosantiago Is the name of the a property that is in `data`. In the example, `a` is one such property (although it is a number, and that `set` call only would make sense if `a` was an object).